# Re-sort Array by key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form which is a bit complicated, because the form fields are dynamically generated from a database. That part works just fine.

When the form is submitted, the POST is an array. The array is as follows:

```
Array ( 
  [ip] => Array ( [0] => Dynamic [1] => Dynamic ) 
  [street_number] => Array ( [0] => 9992 [1] => 9999 ) 
  [street_name] => Array ( [0] => Vision Way [1] => Vision Way ) 
  [suite] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) 
  [city] => Array ( [0] => Brampton [1] => Brampton ) 
  [province] => Array ( [0] => BC [1] => BX ) 
  [postal_code] => Array ( [0] => XXX 1J2 [1] => XXX 1J2 ) 
  [existing_id] => Array ( [0] => new [1] => new ) 
  [line_id] => Array ( [0] => 223 [1] => 223 ) 
  [quote_id] => Array ( [0] => 20220617258463 [1] => 20220617258463 ) 
)
```

Now, I need this array to be sorted by existing_id instead of it being grouped together like this. Basically it should come out as follows:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [ip] => Dynamic[street_number] => 9999
    [street_name] =Vision Way.....
  ) 
  [1] => Array( 
    [ip] => Dynamic[street_number] => 9992.....
  )
)
```

How do I accomplish this? Is there an array function that can do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should be able to rename your form controls to easily get the array that you want in $_POST.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to re-array $_FILES object, which is similar concept. just replace `'name'` with `'ip'`.

```
public static function reArrayFilesObject($file_post)
{
    $result = [];
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $result[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```